# How to load values in ComboBox dynamically using C# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, loading

I have a problem in loading data in ComboBox. I have 30 ComboBox in a windows form. Name of the ComboBox is like cmbStatus1, cmbStatus2, cmbStatus3 .......... cmbStatus30. I want to load the same value using database in ComboBox. My code is :`enter code here`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
{
var comboBox = new CustomComboBox();
comboBox.Name = "cmbStatus" + i.ToString();

comboBox.DataSource = combox.FetchData_Examination_Status();
comboBox.DisplayMember = "ESTATUS";
comboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
//cmbStatus1.Refresh();
}
```

But data is not loaded to this ComboBox. Pls help.

Comment: You forgot to add the new ComboBoxes to an existing container (e.g., `this.Controls.Add(comboBox);`). Btw, set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` before you set the `DataSource`.

Comment: What kind of DataSource is returned by `combox.FetchData_Examination_Status()`?

Comment: Thanks Jimi. Actually I want to load data in existing comboBox without adding new one.

Comment: Since you want to add data to existing Control, why do you create new ones? `var comboBox = new CustomComboBox();` generates a new Object. The `Name` property is irrelevant. If you added your ComboBox controls to a single container (e.g., the Form), you can iterate its `Controls` collection, considering only controls of type ComboBox with a `Name` that starts with `cmbStatus`: `var myCombos = this.Controls.OfType<CustomComboBox>().Where(cb => cb.Name.StartsWith("cmbStatus")).ToList();`. Then iterate the `myCombos` collection.

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
    {
    var myCombos = this.Controls.OfType<CustomComboBox>().Where(cb => cb.Name.StartsWith("cmbStatus")).ToList();
    myCombos[i].DataSource = combox.FetchData_Examination_Status();
    myCombos[i].DisplayMember = "ESTATUS";
    myCombos[i].ValueMember = "ID";
    }                     Still Data is not LOADED TO cmbStatus1, cmbStatus2, cmbStatus3 and so on. @Jimi

Comment: Remove that loop (which is wrong, BTW). Create the list of ComboBoxes as described, the see what controls actually contains (that procedure only retrieves controls that are direct child of a Form, not child of another container, e.g., a GroupBox). Set the value returned by `FetchData_Examination_Status()` to a local variable and inspect the content, see whether it actually contains what you expect and the Fields names match (the letters' case matters). One of these is not what you think.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating new Combo box and not using the combo box on the form. so remove this part of the code

```
 var comboBox = new CustomComboBox();
```

and use

```
yourComboBoxName.DataSource = combox.FetchData_Examination_Status();
```